# Compose an outlook E-mail through Java

Tags: jakarta-mail

I want to compose an outlook E-mail through java on my local machine. Can someone please suggest which library to use and few related sample example's would be great.

Want I am really trying to do is this.

1. compose an outlook email by connecting to outlook with my username and password through java.
2. attach a file and create a HTML message.
3. send it to the recipients

Please help me taking first steps to create this program.

Comment: That is a terrible design decision. Just send the email with javamail.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  reason is every day I have to send a file from share drive to few recipients from outlook. how do I automate this. please suggest me, a sample would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you really want to do is connect to the Exchange mail server and send the message without using the Outlook client application.  As long as your Exchange server has SMTP support enabled, you should be able to do that using JavaMail.  There's documentation, sample programs, and a FAQ.  Start at the [JavaMail project page](http://javamail.java.net).